# How long can a bread dough containing eggs wait before going to the oven?

Tags: bread, eggs

I am waiting until the bread has grown enough. Naturally, outside fridge. However, the dough contains a cracked egg among other ingredients. Will it become unsafe to eat?

I suppose the oven will kill any organism that may start to multiply in the dough.

Comment: So you're affraid your bread will turn bad because it has _an egg_ in it?? Have you seen how many bread recipes have eggs? And most breads rise outside fridges... Besides, what do you mean with _unhealthy_? Is this about food safety or health advice? Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The USDA recommends](https://www.fsis.usda.gov/wps/portal/fsis/topics/food-safety-education/get-answers/food-safety-fact-sheets/egg-products-preparation/shell-eggs-from-farm-to-table/CT_Index/!ut/p/a1/jZDdbsIwDIWfhQewnK4MwSWKhGgHrRD7yXKDMpqESm1SJd4fT0-2XW0aG_aNrfMd2TooUaB06qW1ilrvVPexy8mObdgkm3FW1rNswYrqflPfcM6m2-sEPP4BVPmF_jM1Z__5ywsOXIU1X1uUg6IDtM54FFYTKBdfdYgojPcNRGU0vYNRe4J40JqSoK2FIfjmeU8xDXpQ4TMYFInoOkh6BBN8n2yhB_JA6qnTKPjtrnCNfsMHlN8fZFnqosq342VZ5awe_wR-SfALOB_R0N-J42q-ZG0xOgHESJVh/#25) that raw eggs should not be left at room temperature for more than **two hours**. They also recommend that any recipe including raw eggs should be cooked within **24 hours**. 
However, the USDA always errs on the side of safety - they also recommend (in the same section of the website) that eggs should be cooked until both the white and yolk are firm, which is not necessary to kill bacteria. 
Keeping in line with the USDA's recommendations, you should let the dough rise for a maximum of two hours at room temperature, then move it into the fridge until it doubles in size (or until it rises appropriately).

Comment: Alternately, you can pasteurize eggs by using a sous vide device to hold them at a temp of 57C (134.5F) for two hours.  They will be basically raw, but safe.

Comment: You are making the same mistake as the OP and trying to derive the holding time from the ingredients. That's not how food safety works. You need numbers for the dough, not for the eggs.

Comment: @rumtscho I found this: https://artisanbreadinfive.com/2007/12/19/low-yeast-version-of-our-master-recipe/ which links to the same USDA page. I'm not sure whether you are correct but if you are that website is making the same mistake as well.

Answer (score -2):

The growth of yeasts and the lactic acid bacteria might protect the dough to go south with an unpleasant strange fermentation. So baker's yeast and sourdough protects the dough. However the eggshell is quite often contaminated with Chicken faeces and Salmonella, especially when they live in a chicken factory, beg your pardon. And so Salmohella can be transmitted to the raw egg when you open the egg. Salmonella bacteria can grow in warm conditions, they actually can grow in dough and can survive for a long time on working surfaces. They are harmful und you become sick when you eat things that have reached a critical number of Salmonella.
You won't taste the raw dough, won't you? You will be fine when you bake it. Panettone, Brioche or any cake.
 Baking kills all the bacteriae, are they good or evil. But clean all your things that had contact to the dough. Clean them thoroughly. You are right, there is a reason to be concerned.

(https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/21333150-growth-of-salmonella-enterica-and-staphylococcus-aureus-in-no-knead-bread-dough-during-prolonged-yeast-fermentation/)

Comment: Not all eggs will make your bread full of salmonella; besides, wash the eggs before cracking and it should be fine.

Answer (score -3):

It should be fine, your main concern would be milk based products in the dough. The U.S. Department of Agriculture advises against consuming milk products that have been left out at room temperature. If the dough was left overnight in the refrigerator set to 4C (40F) or below, this is not a concern.

With a refrigerated dough that has been left overnight, the flavor and texture will be similar to the original recipe. If the dough has been left on the counter, it will develop a slightly sour taste. The texture of the bread will become thicker and may not rise as much during the second rise or the final baking. If it is left overnight during the second proof, it will also be a different shape than expected, as over-proofing makes bubbles expand beyond normal and then collapse when they are baked.

Comment: _...advises against consuming milk products that have been left out at room temperature_ - except you're not consuming _the milk_, you incorporated it into the dough. It's not the same thing.